# Yeoman and GruntJS issues

Tags: gruntjs, npm, yeoman

on command terminal to using

```
npm install -g yo
```

it's getting error;

> "npm WARN deprecated this package has been reintegrated into npm and
>   is now out of date with respect to npm
>
> Found potential issues on your machine :("

[image]

What should i have to do to fix it ?

Comment: I believe you just need to update your npm? Do an `npm install -g npm`

Comment: I did it but i think problem is about path but I don't know how to fix it :)